# Turn windows server to evaluation mode

Tags: windows-server-2008

Is there a way to turn a copy of windows server to evaluation?
Reason is that I have a virtual machine which has a few softwares installed on it (which unfortunately cant be installed in an automated fashion), and would like to turn it to evaluation use.
Windows server 2008

Answer (score 2):

`slmgr /upk` or `slmgr -upk` uninstalls product keys from that installation of Windows.

Comment: Thanks. So i'll need to then get a product key for evaluation purposes or let the person who gets the system worry about it!
Also thanks for marking down the question :)